# Postgres 9.6 reload or restart after config changes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I need to change a couple of log config settings in postgresql.conf. How do I know which parameters need a restart or reload?

Is there a list of parameters that need a restart?

Comment: I do that like that: If i change any configuration I reload first. Then check logs, if it says restart is needed then I schedule that restart.

Answer (score 6):

Try this query:

```
SELECT name, context
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name ilike '%log%';
```

The [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/view-pg-settings.html) view gives the context for any setting. `sighup` is a reload and `postmaster` is a restart.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the official documentation:

- [III. Server Administration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/admin.html)

  - [Chapter 19. Server Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html)

    - [19.5. Write Ahead Log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html)
    - [19.8. Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

...depending on whether you are referring to [Write Ahead Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html) or the [Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html).

[19.1. Setting Parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/config-setting.html) also states:

> The configuration file is reread whenever the main server process receives a SIGHUP signal; **this signal is most easily sent by running pg_ctl reload** from the command line or by calling the SQL function pg_reload_conf(). The main server process also propagates this signal to all currently running server processes, so that existing sessions also adopt the new values (this will happen after they complete any currently-executing client command). Alternatively, you can send the signal to a single server process directly. **Some parameters can only be set at server start**; any changes to their entries in the configuration file **will be ignored until** the **server is restarted**. Invalid parameter settings in the configuration file are likewise ignored (but logged) during SIGHUP processing.

So if you read in the documentation that a parameter is only valid on server start, then you need a restart. Otherwise a reload should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are several sources where you can find this information.

1. The documentation for each parameter states if a restart is needed:
     https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html
2. the configuration file `postgresql.conf` has a comment for each parameter that requires a restart. For example:

   ```
   max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
   ```
3. If you change a parameter using `ALTER SYSTEM` you can query the view [`pg_settings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-settings.html) and look at the column `pending_restart`. If that is true, you need to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to change all the parameters in postgresql.conf and just run a reload of Postgres. After that just run the following query to check if restart is needed:

```
SELECT name FROM pg_settings WHERE pending_restart IS true;
```

If this returns an empty result, nothing to do. If it returns something it will tell you which configuration parameters are pending a restart.